# How to quickly generate an array from strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, string

In ruby I can use the following code to generate an array of strings from a to z:

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

Is there a similar function call in Javascript?

Comment: JS does not support this natively, unfortunately

Comment: Note: in Ruby, you would normally not convert to an `Array`, but rather use the `Range` directly, since it is much more memory-efficient.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, ECMAScript does not have a `Range` in its standard library. However, what you can do, is to use the [`Array.from`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.from) factory function to construct an `Array` using a mapping function.

Something like this:

```
const alphabet = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) => i + 97).map(String.fromCharCode);
```

Or, without magic numbers:

```
const charCodeOfA = "a".charCodeAt(0),                //=>  97
    charCodeOfZ = "z".charCodeAt(0),                  //=> 122
    lengthOfAlphabet = charCodeOfZ - charCodeOfA + 1, //=>  26

    alphabet = Array.from({ length: lengthOfAlphabet }, (_, i) => i + charCodeOfA).
        map(String.fromCharCode);
```

In future versions of ECMAScript, it would be nice to use [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) to avoid polluting the namespace with those temporary helper variables:

```
const alphabet = do {
    const charCodeOfA = "a".charCodeAt(0),                //=>  97
        charCodeOfZ = "z".charCodeAt(0),                  //=> 122
        lengthOfAlphabet = charCodeOfZ - charCodeOfA + 1; //=>  26

    Array.from({ length: lengthOfAlphabet }, (_, i) => i + charCodeOfA).
        map(String.fromCharCode)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do that is

```js
var alphabet =[];
for(var i = "a".charCodeAt(0); i <= "z".charCodeAt(0); i++) {
        alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i))

}
```

Comment: Great idea! You could swap out the `...charCodeAt...` with the char values (97 & 122) for a shorter and more performant solution.